# Failing in Running Multiple Promises ordered on App-Initialization with Angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, initializer

I have two promises (ConfigurationServices and roleService) and I want to initalize first ConfigurationService-Singleton to get some Configurationdata and then initialize RoleService-Singleton to get RoleInformation based on the given configuration.

Im using Angular 5 and this is how the code looks like:

That is the Initializer:

```
{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: configurationFactory,
      deps: [
        ConfigurationService,
        RoleService
      ],
      multi: true
    },
```

Here I try to introduce an Order in the Initialization process:

```
export function configurationFactory(configurationService: ConfigurationService, roleService: RoleService): Function {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return configurationService.fetchConfiguration()
        .then(data => {
          return roleService.requestRole()
        })
        .then((data) => {
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          reject();
        });
    });
  };
}
```

Here is the requestRole-Promise:

```
public requestRole(): Promise<any> {
    return this.gmcService.getRole().pipe(
      tap(  role => {
        this._role=role;
        this._isReadWriteUser = this._role === this.READ_WRITE_ABBREVIATION;
      })

    ).toPromise();
  }
```

Here is the configuration-Promise:

```
fetchConfiguration(): Promise<ConfigurationDTO> {
    const result: Observable<ConfigurationDTO> = this.httpClient.get<ConfigurationDTO>(environment.configuration);
    const promise: Promise<ConfigurationDTO> = result.toPromise();
    promise.then(configuration => {
      this.configuration = configuration;
      console.log('configuration: ' + JSON.stringify(configuration));
    });
    return promise;
```

the Initialization of Configurationservice seems to fail, because there is no ConfigurationDTo in the Configrationservice, which other services  are requesting , so im getting an undefined error -> what im doing wrong?

Comment: hey there, i tried to reproduce the error you described in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mulve3) but i couldn't. it all works just fine. if you haven't solved it yet, can you take a look at the repo and try to reproduce the problem.